# Calculate time complexity of an algorithm in big theta

Tags: python, time-complexity

```py
s = 0 

for i in range(N) :
    for j in range(i):
        s += j
```

What is the time complexity of this algorithm in big theta notation?

Comment: The same as its big-O and Omega: Theta(n²).

Answer (score 0):

You can consider it for different values of `i`:

- `i=1` => number of runs of `s+=j` = 1
- `i=2` => number of runs of `s+=j` = 2
- `i=3` => number of runs of `s+=j` = 3

  ...
- 'i=N' => number of runs of `s+=j` = N

So in total we have: `1 + 2 + ... N = N(N+1) / 2`

Therefore, the running time will be: θ(N<sup>2</sup>)